# Add columnname and data from datatable to a dictionary? C#

Tags: c#

I am looping through a datatable and currently I do

```
string customerId = row["CustomerId"].ToString();
string companyName = row["Company Name"].ToString();
```

Instead of declaring every variable how do I add these do a dictionary?
I was thinking something like:

```
foreach (DataRow row in customerTbl.Rows)
    {
     Dictionary<string, string> customerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     customerDictionary.Add(row[].ToString(), row[].ToString());
```

so yeah, how do I get the row name and value into there?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I guess I didn't give you all information about what I am trying to do.
I query a database for a customer and populate a datatable with about 50 columns, I use the customer id to query another database and get the same customer from there. I then want to compare all 50 fields from both databases for the same customer and check if any field is different. I thought I could add the column name with the value in a dictionary for each row for each customer and then with two loops check if the values for the same key (column name) differs, is this a totally wrong approach?

having an if (customerId1 != customerId2 || customerName1 != customerName2 || and so on for 50 fields is not very good.

Comment: what is the "key" to that dictionary intended to be?

Comment: @Marc, I'm guessing CustomerId

Comment: This line `Dictionary<string, string> customerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();` should be placed before the `for` loop, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a generic solution to this kind of thing? If so does your DataTable always contain 2 columns where the first can be treated as the dictionary key and the second the value? If so, then simply use the column index instead of the column name

```
var customerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();    
foreach (DataRow row in customerTbl.Rows)
   customerDictionary.Add(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString());
```

If the values in the customerId and CompanyName columns are never null then instead of using ToString(), you can cast the values to a string

```
customerDictionary.Add((string)row[0], (string)row[1]);
```

FYI, the DataTable has a search capability as well (the Find() method). If you set up a primary key column the search will be extremely fast and you may not need to copy the data from a DataTable to a Dictionary.

Edit : A complete working example of one way of doing this in C# code as per the OPs edited question

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var table1 = GetCustomersFromFirst();
      var table2 = GetCustomersFromSecond();

      foreach (DataRow row in table1.Rows)
      {
        var foundRows = table2.Select("CustomerId = " + (string)row[0]);
        if (foundRows.Length == 1)
        {
          var foundRow = foundRows[0];
          foreach (DataColumn col in table1.Columns)
          {
            var valueOfColumnFromTable1 = row[col.Ordinal].ToString();
            var valueOfColumnFromTable2 = foundRow[col.Ordinal].ToString();
            if (String.Compare(valueOfColumnFromTable1, valueOfColumnFromTable2) != 0)
            {
              //the colum values are not the same.
            }

          }
        }
        else
        {
          // Something is wrong since more than one matching record was found
          // or no matching records were found.
        }
      }
    }

    static DataTable GetCustomersFromFirst()
    {
      var dt = GetInitializedCustomerDataTable();
      var row = dt.NewRow();
      row[0] = "1";
      row[1] = "CompanyA";
      dt.Rows.Add(row);

      row = dt.NewRow();
      row[0] = "2";
      row[1] = "CompanyB";
      dt.Rows.Add(row);

      row = dt.NewRow();
      row[0] = "3";
      row[1] = "CompanyC";
      dt.Rows.Add(row);

      return dt;
    }

    static DataTable GetCustomersFromSecond()
    {
      var dt = GetInitializedCustomerDataTable();
      var row = dt.NewRow();
      row[0] = "1";
      row[1] = "CompanyA";
      dt.Rows.Add(row);

      row = dt.NewRow();
      row[0] = "2";
      row[1] = "CompanyD";
      dt.Rows.Add(row);

      row = dt.NewRow();
      row[0] = "3";
      row[1] = "CompanyC";
      dt.Rows.Add(row);

      return dt;
    }

    static DataTable GetInitializedCustomerDataTable()
    {
      var dt = new DataTable();
      dt.Columns.Add("CustomerId", typeof(string));
      dt.Columns.Add("CompanyName", typeof(string));
      return dt;
    }
  }
```

In the test data, the 2nd row does not match. So it should fall into the condition where the comment says:
//the colum values are not the same.

Personally, I'd look at doing this in the database itself.

Comment: I'd stick to using the DataTables. You'd iterate over one DataTables row and "Find()" the matching record in the second DataTable. Then iterate over all of the columns in both and do your check. The assumption here is that the columns in both DataTables are in the same order.

Comment: @Nick, I've updated my answer to include a working sample of how you can do this.

Comment: I have no control (apart from read) over the databases and from one of them I get the data via a web service which actually returns a customer object with the same properties. Thanks for your extensive answer though.

Comment: Then it might be better for you to convert your DataTable to a Dictionary as you were attempting. unless you use reflection, you'll need to do a property by property check. Or, the other way is convert your customer list to a DataTable and use the code I provided. Either ways, you've converting one to another. Or stuff your customers into a dictionary with the appropriate key. Iterate over your DataTable's row, and find the customer using the key and then do a column to property match.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Dictionary<string, string> customerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (DataRow row in customerTbl.Rows)
{         
     if(row["CustomerId"] != null && customerDictionay.ContainsKey("CustomerId") == false)
     {
         customerDictionary.Add(row["CustomerID"].ToString(), row["CompanyName"] as string);
     }
}
```

Comment: You *might* want to declare the dictionary variable *outside* the loop. =)

Answer (score 0):

Just a question, what's the benefit of putting the values in a dictionary? You are basically just eliminating the need of writing .ToString() when accessing the values...i.e, instead of:

```
row["CustomerID"].ToString();
```

you write

```
customerDictionary["CustomerID"];
```

Or have I missed something?

Comment: Dictionaries are optimized for lookup - hence the name "Dictionary". =) Also, he might not want to send a DataTable up the hierarchy of his business logic.